# xmlrpc.php?rsd shown in google extended results

Tags: wordpress, search

I have a website based on wordpress and newly google shows extended results of this webpage (hope you know what i mean by extended results)
So there are the pages, which should be there like "contact", "services" or "info" but theres also one which shouldn't appear in the results: "domain.xx/xmlrpc.php?rsd". it shows in the results as "wordpress http://..." which is pretty ugly.

i tried to "downgrade" (sorry, dont know the exact translation for this in english) the page in google webmastertools about one week ago, but theres no effect. Actually since then it appears as the second link in the results. before it was the last one..

any hints to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First (and recommended way): In Google Webmaster Tools go to `Configuration->Sitelinks` and demote your xmlrpc URL.

Second way: Go to `Optimization` and `Remove URL` and enter your xmlrpc.php URL there. It will take some time before the URL is removed.

Third way: Block Google to access xmlrpc URL with the help of robots.txt file.

Fourth way: Block Google to access xmlrpc URL with the help of .htaccess file.